# In Maven, is SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT actually valid SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven, versioning, semantic-versioning

In Maven, is SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT a valid SNAPSHOT?

If valid, what happens if somebody released that "SNAPSHOT", will that still be a SNAPSHOT?

Is SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT a snapshot of a snapshot? or is it just something that is not a snapshot at all?

Comment: A rather philosophical question. I guess the answer is not well defined because the actual implementations of Maven plugins may have different technical approaches how they determine if a version is actually a SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Yes it is a valid SNAPSHOT cause it ends with `-SNAPSHOT`. If all plugins working correctly (which I'm not 100% sure about) this will work but I can't recommend that. Use something like `1-SNAPSHOT`.. Furthermore I would try to prevent releasing a `SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT` cause that is completely confusing. The question could be: Should Maven prevent a version like `SNAPSHOT.*`?